# Compound summation: I would like to create a compound query which gets the individual sum of two columns from two different tables and then sum them

Tags: sql, metabase

```
select sum(saved_amount - withdrawal_amount) from goal_withdrawal as sum1;

union 

select suM(amount) from phone_verification as sum2;

select sum1  + sum2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use select statements within the select statements to get what you want.
I've worked out the following example:

```
--Creating some fake-data
DECLARE @goal_withdrawal TABLE (saved_amount int, withdrawal_amount int);
INSERT INTO @goal_withdrawal VALUES (100,100);
INSERT INTO @goal_withdrawal VALUES (150,100);
INSERT INTO @goal_withdrawal VALUES (200,125);

DECLARE @phone_verification TABLE (amount int);
INSERT INTO @phone_verification VALUES (100);
INSERT INTO @phone_verification VALUES (150);

SELECT 
    (
        SELECT (SUM(saved_amount) - SUM(withdrawal_amount)) 
        FROM @goal_withdrawal
    ) AS sum1,
    (
        SELECT SUM(amount) 
        FROM @phone_verification
    ) AS sum2,
    (
        SELECT (SUM(saved_amount) - SUM(withdrawal_amount)) 
        FROM @goal_withdrawal
    ) 
    + 
    (
        SELECT SUM(amount) 
        FROM @phone_verification
    ) AS sum3
```

Resulting in three columns:

- Sum1 being 125
- Sum2 being 250
- Sum3 being 375